# Differentiability of $\frac{\sin(x)}{|x|+\cos(x)}$

Tags: calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by $f(x)= \frac{\sin(x)}{|x|+\cos(x)}$.

I have to check whether $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ or not. I need  a start because I am worrying about the absolute value sign. What should the approach be?

Comment: At $x = 0$, write the function in 2 parts, as $x \lt 0$, and $x \ge 0$. Use $|x| = -x$, $\sin (-x) = -x$ and $\cos (-x) = \cos x$ when $x \lt 0$. At the other point, $\pi/2$, there won't be much of a problem for you

Comment: @Shailesh I found explicit expression for derivative for x greater than j0 and x less than 0. But right handed limit does not exists using definition of f'(X). So it is not differentiable at 0. Is that right?

Comment: Right hand limit should be 1

Comment: @Shailesh left hand limit DNE

Comment: See answer posted

Answer (score 1):

You are concerned with the expression

$$\frac{f(t) - f(0)}{t} = \frac{\sin t}{t(|t| + \cos t)}$$

as $t$ approaches from the left and from the right. You want these limits to be equal.

From the right, $\frac{\sin t}{t} \to 1$ and $\frac{1}{|t| + \cos t} \to 1$ so the entire limit goes to $1$.

From the left, $\frac{\sin t}{t} \to 1$ and $\frac{1}{|t| + \cos t} \to 1$ so the entire limit goes to $1$.

Thus, the function is differentiable here.

You could also notice that, when $t$ is small, $|t|$ in the denominator is inconsequential compared to $\cos t$, so the function is the same as $\frac{\sin t}{\cos t} = \tan t$ which is differentiable at $0$.

Comment: but by finding two explicit expressions for derivative, left hand limit is not equal to right hand limit